# $g_n(z)=z^n$ uniformly on $D={z: |z|<1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am looking at this example:

$g_n(z)=z^n$ and domain 
$D={z: |z|<1}$

I see that every $g_n$ will converge to 0 for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thus it converges.

Now, how can I show that it is or is not uniformly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compute the limit of $g_n\left(1-\frac1n\right)$ when $n\to\infty$. If the limit exists and is not zero, the convergence cannot be uniform on the disk $D$.

Once this is done, you might note that $1-\frac1n$ converges to $1$ which is not in the disk $D$ and try to imagine subsets of $D$ on which the convergence is uniform.

**Edit:** In view of the comments, let us recall the following facts:

- For every $c$, $\left(1-\frac{c}n\right)^n\to\mathrm e^{-c}$ when $n\to\infty$.
- For every $c$ and positive $a\gt1$, $\left(1-\frac{c}{n^a}\right)^n\to1$.
- For every $c\ne0$ and positive $a\lt1$, $\left(1-\frac{c}{n^a}\right)^n\to0$.
- Similar statements hold for the limit of $\left(1-x_n\right)^n$ for sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to0$, the limit depending on the asymptotics of $x_n$.

Comment: Can I conclude now: $g_n$ not uniformly on $D$? And where did you get the $1-1/n$ from?

Comment: "Can I conclude" **IF** you computed the limit I suggest in my answer and **IF** you checked that this limit is not zero, then you can conclude this. // "where did you get the 1−1/n from?" If the functions were defined at 1, the point 1 would directly contradict the convergence to zero. Hence the idea to pick some points in D close to 1.

Comment: Okay, yes I did that. How is uniform convergence then different from 'normal' convergence?

Comment: Uniform convergence (to zero): $\forall\varepsilon,\exists N,\forall x,\forall n\geqslant N,|f_n(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon$. Simple convergence (to zero): $\forall\varepsilon,\forall x,\exists N,\forall n\geqslant N,|f_n(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon$. The second case is easier since $N$ can depend on $x$. In fact the first case happens when the second case happens **and** when additionally $N$ in the second case can be made independent of $x$.

Comment: For simple convergence, the stragy for checking is clear to me: I simply look at the individual terms and see whether they go to 0 if $n\rightarrow 0$. What is the general strategy for checking uniform convergence? Which steps do I have to take?

Comment: One option is to reread your proof of simple convergence step by step and to see if the arguments used can be made *uniform* with respect to the point $x$.

Comment: No thanks. Sorry.

Comment: I don't still get it... Suppose I want to make $g_n$ uniformly now on a disk. How should I choose $D$ then?

Comment: Is $1-e^{-n}$ or $1-1/n^k$, $k=1,2,3,4,...$ also valid to stubstitute (instead of $1-1/n$)?

Comment: Just check whether the limit along these sequences is 0 or not (it is (except $1-1/n^k$ for $k=1$, which is the sequence in my answer), hence these prove nothing). More interesting is $g_n(1-1/\sqrt{n})$. Do you see why?

Comment: It has something to do with that it converges more slowly, I guess...

Comment: Why is that if the limit exists and is not $0$ that the convergence cannot be uniform on disk $D$?

Comment: About concrete examples of sequences, see Edit. About non uniform convergence: what can you say about $\|g_n\|_\infty$ when what you say happens?

Comment: $|| g_n ||_{\infty}$ is not $0$ then

Comment: More importantly, $\|g_n\|_\infty$ does not converge to zero.